# Как на переменную класса назначить значение из переменной другого класса?

Tags: c#

Есть у меня класс, на поле которого мне нужно повесить значение получаемое в методе другого класса.

Т.е. в строку подключения вставить данные, которые читаются методом класса Config.

Вот так это выглядит на практике. 
[image: так]
Оно у меня ругается:

> "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property"

Вот мой код:

```
namespace DBSync
{

    class FireBird
    {
        Config config;
        public FireBird(Config config)
        {
            this.config = config;
        }

        string connectionString =
                 "User=SYSDBA;" +
                 "Password=masterkey;" +
                 "Database=" + config
                 "DataSource=localhost;" +
                 "Port=3050;" +
                 "Dialect=3;" +
                 "Charset=NONE;" +
                 "Role=;" +
                 "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                 "Pooling=true;" +
                 "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                 "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                 "Packet Size=8192;" +
                 "ServerType=0";
```

Вот код той части, что конфиг читает:

```
namespace DBSync
{
    public class Config
    {
       string fbLogin;
       string fbPass;
       string fbPath;

       string PGLogin;
       string PGPass;

       string SQLLitePath;

       public void parseConfig()
       {
```

Вопрос -- как это сделать? И почему сейчас не получается?

Comment: В первом блоке кода синтаксис нарушен. Перенесите присваивание connectionString выше, в конструктор -- сейчас оно у вас висит вне методов, прямо в теле класса. Кроме того, строка где `"Database=" + config` -- здесь нехватает обращения к полю config и знака `+` после этого.

Comment: @nzeemin по первой части вашего ответа, вы это имеете ввиду? http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/18/5714b7ef3e43a.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка ясно говорит о том, что нельзя использовать не статические поля для инициализации полей не в конструкторе.

Таким образом для решения нужно перенести инициализацию в конструктор

```
public FireBird(Config config)
{
    this.config = config;
    this.connectionStroing = "..."+
                             "..."+this.config+
                             "..."
}
```

Comment: тоесть объявление строки подключения идет до конструктора, а в конструкторе просто инициализация?

У меня кстати заработал `config` без `this`. Почему?

Правильно сделал что все руками сделал паблик или надо было как-то иначе? http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/18/5714b8e03ad02.png

Comment: @Suliman, да, объявление стандартно _вне_ конструктора, в конструкторе - _инициализация_. Вполне закономерно, что `config` заработал Без `this`, так как у вас есть параметр `config`. Последний вопрос и картинку не понял

Comment: так а если бы я не передавал в класс экземпляр config, то тогда бы и с this и без него не смог бы обратиться? Или смог бы?

По второму вопросу. Ну я там все поля как public сделал. Это правильно?

Comment: @Suliman, если бы не передавался экземпляр конфига, то работало бы с `this`, так как есть поле `config`, но в момент выполнения скорее всего будет `NullReferenceException` так как это поле не инициализировано, так как не передан экземпляр конфига. По `Public` - в теории **все** поля должны быть приватные или protected, так как поля - это данные, а данные должны быть скрыты :)

Comment: а на что `this` бы тогда указывал? Я думал он указывает на переменные текущего класса. А тут тогда как?

Comment: @Suliman, `this` и продолжил бы указывать на _экземпляр_ текущего класса, а так как поле этого экземпляра _null_ так как его не инициализировали, то при попытке обращения к нему получили бы исключение